# How do I partition a matrix into blocks and replace zeros with dots?

Tags: matrices, arrays

I am using this command

```latex
\begin{equation} 
W =  \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)   
\end{equation}
```

to display a 9x9 matrix.

I would like to show this matrix as partitioned into 3x3 blocks, and also the zeros replaced with dots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing a “search and replace” would not be a big problem, but if there's a dirty trick available…

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
W =  \left(\mathcode`0=\cdot
\begin{array}{ *{3}{c} | *{3}{c} | *{3}{c} }
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the duration of the group initiate by `\left(`, I'm telling TeX that `0` in math mode (that is, in every cell) should be interpreted as `\cdot`.

Comment: Thanks! I got this to work--but not entirely so, trying to adapt it to a 16 x 16 into 4 x 4 blocks, as just added to my original question.

Comment: My apologies--I have to add the \hline commands--which I hadn't noticed before--so I'll delete that addendum to my question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use string replacement within LaTeX (xstring and collcell packages). For the blocks, I use dashed lines from arydshln (: in header and \hdashline in rows).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,arydshln}
\usepackage{xstring,collcell}

\newcommand{\ToDot}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{0}{\cdot}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
W =  \left(
\begin{array}{ *{3}{>{\collectcell\ToDot}c<{\endcollectcell}} : 
  *{3}{>{\collectcell\ToDot}c<{\endcollectcell}} : 
  *{3}{>{\collectcell\ToDot}c<{\endcollectcell}}}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hdashline
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hdashline
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)   
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]